# Matcha testing / How to get stats of operations per second

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

Trying to implement Levenshtein algorithm with JS. Found in github stats about operation per seconds. In github's readme was this stat image. How to get this statistics with matcha? with 'npm run bench' benchmarking is working, but i need stats about op/s. Sorry for maybe stupid questions, Im newbie in Js world

Comment: https://ibb.co/StHcg9R here the stats i need

Comment: Do you have a link to the repository?